# Position image on top of another html element

Tags: html

I have the following:

[image]

here is the html code:

```
<p>
    <label>Select Roles</label>
    <span id="dualselect" class="dualselect">
        <img id="loading1"  src="@Url.Content("~/content/template/images/loaders/loader7.gif")" alt="Img Not Avalible" />
        <select name="RolesSelect" id="dualSelectRoles1" multiple="multiple" size="10">
            <option value="2">Avaliable Roles</option>
        </select>

        <span class="ds_arrow">
            <span class="arrow ds_prev">&laquo;</span>
            <span class="arrow ds_next">&raquo;</span>
        </span>
        <img id="loading2"  src="@Url.Content("~/content/template/images/loaders/loader7.gif")" alt="Img Not Avalible" />
        <select name="select4" multiple="multiple" id="dualSelectRoles2" size="10">
            <option value="1">Users Roles</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</p>
<p class="stdformbutton">
    <button class="submit radius2" type="submit">Save</button>
</p>
```

how can I position each image so that it is in the middle (and ontop) of the box?

Answer (score 1):

You need to place a wrapper around the select & loader image, like this:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <select name="select4" multiple="multiple" size="10">   
        <option value="1">Users Roles</option>
    </select>
    <img src="http://www.ajaxload.info/cache/FF/FF/FF/00/00/00/1-0.gif" />
</div>
```

...and then absolutely position it inside the box, like this:

**CSS**

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px; // half the loader width
    margin-top: -8px; // half the loader height
}

div, select {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKh3p/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `position:fixed;` style.

Assign your image a class:

```
<img id="loading1" class="loading" ... />
```

Now style it using `CSS`:

```
.loading{
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    right: 500px;
}
```